# Laravel PHPUnit not working and using old version

Tags: laravel, phpunit

Whenever I run PHPUnit in Command Prompt, I get this.

```
C:\Users\John\laravel-projects\layout-test\>phpunit tests\Unit\ExampleTest.php
PHPUnit 3.7.21 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Configuration read from C:\Users\John\laravel-projects\layout-test\phpunit.xml


Time: 0 seconds, Memory: 4.00Mb
```

It doesn't execute the command but only execute whatever's inside the `phpunit.xml` file. However if I run phpunit using: 
`vendor\bin\phpunit tests\Unit\ExampleTest.php` command, the test runs successfully. Is there a way to fix this? I'm currently using Laravel version 5.6.

Comment: When your run the command normally are you just running `phpunit` or `vendor\bin\phpunit`?

Comment: @RossWilson I'm running `phpunit` alone.

Comment: Are you running this from a bash window or cmd?

Comment: @RossWilson Thank you for answering. I'm running this in cmd. When I run `phpunit` alone I get version 3.7.21 but if I run from the vendor, I get the latest version. Is there a way to fix this without going to vendor?